# Reindex is in processing since 10 days why it is not going to complete in magento2

Tags: magento2, reindex

> See the date of reindex in processing since 10 days why it is not going to finish
>   Cron jobs running in every 21 hours for reindex
>   I try also manually reindex but taking too long time in days
>   Also I am using CDN and AWS server

[image]

Comment: You can try manually once . if it will successfully re-indexing then i think it will work on cron job as well.

Comment: no it is not working manually

Comment: So now you can find error in system or exception log from that you can check what is the problem occurring on re-index time.

Comment: You need to run bin/magento indexer:reset catalog_product_attribute and then again run bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_attribute This will reset the indexer and reindex again.

Answer (score 1):

```
bin/magento indexer:reset catalog_product_attribute
```

after that check the state of the index with

```
bin/magento indexer:status catalog_product_attribute
```

the first debugging step you should do is reindexing in verbose mode

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_attribute -vvv
```

if that doesn't give usefull information use a step-bystep debugger like xdebug

Answer (score 0):

Please try to `reindex` via `SSH / CLI` by using the below command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Hope the issue will get be fixed.

Comment: yes command right but taking too much time in days

Comment: provide other solution please

Answer (score 0):

Looks like job was killed and status will never back again.

Please change it manually by
`php bin/magento indexer:reset <index name>`

Comment: after reset when i run reindex again then  taking too much time in days

Comment: provide other solution please